# extracting data from Named Pipes

Tags: bash, pipe

so I've got the following in a bash script

```
mknod fifoPipe p
$CMDPATH/cmd outputFile=fifoPipe &

cat fifoPipe | $CMDPATH/filterProgram > thefile.ext
```

The data that is being passed into the pipe out of cmd is not text data and using cat to get it out of the pipe into the filter just seems messy, anyone have any ideas on how to make this work 'better'?

Comment: what happens when you do `outputFile=-`?

Comment: `$CMDPATH/filterProgram < fifoPipe > thefile.ext`?

Comment: What are the `cmd` and `filterProgram` you’re using? Should `cmd` produce text, or the binary output is expected? What do you mean by “better”? What is the problem, really? Is the comment by twalberg the solution you want? `cat` should be used only when multiple files are to be con`cat`enated. Are you looking for `tee` command that writes its input both to a file and its standard output?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that $CMDPATH/cmd cannot itself write to the standard output, but instead expects an output file name as an argument. I would try to fool it like this:

```
$CMDPATH/cmd outputFile=/dev/stdout | $CMDPATH/filterProgram > thefile.ext
```

Comment: The problem with doing this is that I get log outout on stdout, and error outout on stderr, both of which I am logging elsewhere... It is a good idea though.

Comment: Then you may use proces substitution: `$CMDPATH/cmd outputFile=>($CMDPATH/filterProgram > thefile.ext)`

Comment: Thanks again - I'm specifically using named pipes because the pipes can't get closed by the internal program by mistake (a problem when interfacing with C-Programs that other people have written).